# Can i still get bcc?

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

I had bitcoin in my blockchain.info wallet when the hard fork happened but I transferred it since to gemini exchange can i still get bch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the BTC was in your blockchain wallet when the fork happened, then surely you can access your BCH right now.

As after fork, they both have different chain, so transferring your BTC after the fork does not have any effect on your BCH.

Infact, it is a recommended step by me to transfer your BTC before you try to access your BCH through wallets present right now. Why? Because these wallets are not completely tested for bugs.

Coming back to your question, how to access your BCH? Just login to blockchain.info and go to settings then wallet.

In there, access your private key of the wallet where you had your BTC before the fork.

Now use any of the online wallets present which can retireve your BCH through your private key.

Now, you can access your BCH and spend it as well.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I first created a coinomi wallet (bch) then I got the private keys from here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/OmniLayer/omniwallet/wiki/Exporting-Private-Key-from-Blockchain.info-and-Importing-to-Omniwallet.org&ved=0ahUKEwiv1e283P_VAhUqrlQKHQG_DcoQFggoMAE&usg=AFQjCNHBAUp0jmlterwNhznyJuVfVQLf1Q then I select sweep wallet and it showed up right away

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can recover your private keys from blockchain.info and send BCC coins from them.

Comment: You write I can recover my private keys. But I don't have my btc in blockchain.info anymore it's in gemini.,you think I can still recover my keys in blockchain.info.

Comment: You should login into your bc.i account and recover your private keys (which are empty for BTC, but still holding BCH). May be recovering is possible by using 12-word seed phrase on some service, but I can not recommend any to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tools to do it will be released soon. See https://blog.blockchain.com/2017/08/22/bitcoin-cash-update/

Comment: But I don't have my btc in blockchain.info anymore it's in gemini.,you think I can still recover my keys in blockchain.info ?

Comment: Normally yes, the BCH didn't move along with the BTC.